# (JWT) Should I store both access token and refresh token in localStorage?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jwt

I'm having trouble with storing refresh token in `HttpOnly cookies`, simply because the backend and the frontend must be on the same domain for cookies to work, and I'm not good enough with NGINX to setup the reverse proxy.

For that reason, I have prepared the auth flow as follows:

[image]

I intend to store both access token and refresh token in localStorage and also in database for invalidating them if needed.

Everytime the access token expires, the client send the refresh token to `/refresh` for new pair of tokens, the old pair of tokens would then be replaced by the new pair in the database.

The tokens from the client are invalid if they do not match those found in the database.

### The problem

If an XSS attack were to occur during the night when the user is not active, the hacker could use the refresh token indefinitely until the user becomes active again.

I want to know what is the correct approach to JWT if **no cookies are used**. I'm all ears for any insight you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your flow looks correct. (But there is probably no need to store the access token in the backend DB. You normally don't do that I would say.)

You need a safe storage for exactly that reason you are fearing, and that attack vector not really avoidable in any other way. **Safe storage is either cookie storage or Session Storage.** If you cannot use cookies, use session storage.

If the refresh token is stolen, there is not much you can do about it during that night. Once the user again tries to access your service, you can detect usage of an old refresh token and log out the user as a safety measure. If you require the user to enter the old password upon pw changes, you have prevented the hacker from changing pw of the account. Once the real user changes pw, you do a logout that removes the current refresh token from the backend DB, and the user is again in control of the account. (But if the vulnerability first used is still there, you are shot to get hijacked again.)

(The session storage is used by for example Auth0, see [this blog post](https://auth0.com/blog/amp/secure-browser-storage-the-facts/) for more info on their specific setup that looks kind of close to yours.)

**Then you need to protect yourself using proper CORS policy on top of that of course.**